# Unexpected token - loadPreLoadFiles - AdonisJS

Tags: javascript, error-handling, preload, adonis.js, unexpected-token

After creating an AdonisJS app, I get following error message when trying to run:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '...'


1 anonymous
  C:\Users\berez\adonisjs-stripe\node_modules\@adonisjs\ignitor\src\Ignitor\index.js:376

2 Ignitor._loadPreLoadFiles
  C:\Users\berez\adonisjs-stripe\node_modules\@adonisjs\ignitor\src\Ignitor\index.js:368

Application crashed, make sure to kill all related running process, fix the issue and re-run the app
```

Checked the mentioned index.js file (unedited), and following can be found at the referenced lines:

```
/**
* Load all the files that are supposed to be preloaded
*
* @method _loadPreLoadFiles
*
* @return {void}
*
* @private
*/
_loadPreLoadFiles () {
this._callHooks('before', 'preloading')
debug('preloading files %j', this._preLoadFiles)
debug('optional set %j', this._optionals)
this._preLoadFiles.forEach((file) => {
const filePath = path.isAbsolute(file) ? file : path.join(this._appRoot, file)
/**
* Require file when it's not optional or when optional
* file exists
*/
if (!this._isOptional(file) || this._fileExists(filePath)) {
require(filePath)
}
})
this._callHooks('after', 'preloading')
}
```

line 376: require(filePath)

line 368: this._preLoadFiles.forEach((file) => {

Any idea what can be the issue?

Comment: What is your node version? AdonisJs(v4) requires the node version to be greater than 8.0.0. The error is related to the spread operator used by adonisJs ignitor package.

Comment: I have followings installed:
NodeJS: 14.16.1
npm: 7.12.0
AdonisJS 3.2

Comment: These look fine, The ignitor loads all the files under the app directory before starting the HTTP server, which indicates that one of your own files has some invalid syntax. You can track it down by removing your last changes.